How to create a sliding tile in JavaScript
I am unable to create sliding tiles using the tiles created using the array. However, I can create a sliding tile using a hard coded green tile and changing the --x and --y css variables. That said, this is what I want to be able to achieve using the tiles created in my array. This is how the HTML element looks like for my array based tile. <div class="tile" style="--x: 3; --y: 0; transform: translate(calc(var(--x) * var(--cell-size)), calc(var(--y) * var(--cell-size)));">2</div> whereas the green one looks like this <div class="tile" id="green">slides</div> but I can dynamically change it's y and x position on the grid. Click the left arrow on the keyboard to to see that based array tiles do not smoothly slide they just jump to their next position or really I want to say they never really move positions.


const data = [
    [2, 0, 0, 2],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [4, 0, 4, 0]
]

const DIMENSION = 4;
const CELL_SIZE = 20;
 class Grid {
    constructor(graphElement) {
        graphElement.style.setProperty("--grid-size", DIMENSION);
        graphElement.style.setProperty("--cell-size", `${CELL_SIZE}vmin`);
        this.processGrid(graphElement);
    }

    processGrid(graphElement) {
        this.board = [];
        for (let row = 0; row < DIMENSION; row++) {
            this.board[row] = [];
            for (let col = 0; col < DIMENSION; col++) {
                const tile = new Tile(data[row][col], row, col);
                graphElement.appendChild(tile.tileElement);
                this.board[row][col] = tile;
                tile.updateTile();
            }
        }
    }

    slideLeft() {
        for (let r = 0; r < DIMENSION; r++) {
            const newRow = this.slide(this.board[r].map(tile => tile.value));
            for (let c = 0; c < DIMENSION; c++) {
                const num = newRow[c];
                const tile = this.board[r][c];
                tile.setValue(num);
                tile.updateTile();
            }
        }
    }

    slide(row) {
        row = this.filterZero(row);
        let score = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < row.length - 1; i++) {
            if (row[i] === row[i + 1]) {
                row[i] *= 2;
                row[i + 1] = 0;
                score += row[i];
            }
        }

        row = this.filterZero(row);
        while (row.length < DIMENSION) {
            row.push(0);
        }
        return row;
    }

    filterZero(row) {
        return row.filter(num => num !== 0);
    }
}

class Tile {
    constructor(value, row, col) {
        this.value = value;
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
        this.createTile();
    }

    createTile() {
        this.tileElement = document.createElement('div');
        this.tileElement.classList.add('tile');
    }

    setValue(value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.tileElement.textContent = this.value !== 0 ? this.value : "";
        const power = Math.log2(this.value);
        const backgroundLightness = 100 - power * 9;
        this.tileElement.style.setProperty("--background-lightness", `${backgroundLightness}%`);
        this.tileElement.style.setProperty("--text-lightness", `${backgroundLightness <= 50 ? 90 : 10}%`);
    }
    updateTile() {
        this.tileElement.textContent = "";
        if (this.value > 0) {
            this.tileElement.textContent = this.value;
        }
        this.setValue(this.value);
        this.setPosition(this.row, this.col);
    }

    setPosition(row, col) {
        this.tileElement.style.setProperty("--x", col);
        this.tileElement.style.setProperty("--y", row);
        this.tileElement.style.transform = `translate(calc(var(--x) * var(--cell-size)), calc(var(--y) * var(--cell-size)))`;
    }
}


const gElement = document.querySelector('section.grid');
const grid = new Grid(gElement);

document.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
    if (e.code == "ArrowLeft") {
        grid.slideLeft();
    }
});
body {
    font-family: system-ui;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #333;
}

main.main {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

section.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-size), var(--cell-size));
    grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-size), var(--cell-size));
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 3px solid black;
}

div.cell {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #aaa;
    z-index: 0;
}

div.tile {
    --x: 2;
    /* Changing this values will directly slide the green tiles */
    --y: 2;
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: var(--cell-size);
    height: var(--cell-size);
    font-size: 3.5vmin;
    transform: translate3d(calc(var(--x) * var(--cell-size)), calc(var(--y) * var(--cell-size)), 0);
    background-color: hsl(200, 50%, var(--background-lightness));
    color: hsl(200, 25%, var(--text-lightness));
    will-change: transform, --x, --y;
    transition: transform 600ms ease, --x 600ms ease, --y 600ms ease;
}

div#green {
    background-color: green;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Game</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>2048</h1>

    <h2>Score: <span id="score">0</span></h2>


    <main class="main">
        <section class="grid">
            <div class="tile" id="green">slides</div>
        </section>

    </main>

    <script src="js/ui.js" type="module"></script>
</body>

</html>




Your other tiles do slide if the --x or --y on them is modified. The problem is that you are not modifying them. When I press the left arrow, the "2" at the top right, for example, it is just updated to no longer contain a 2. If you instead change the --x or --y on it, it will slide. It seems there is potentially an issue with what you think the code is even doing?
